# Prettyfaces programmatic configuration

Tags: primefaces, tomcat7, jsf-2.2, prettyfaces

## Questions

1. Is there any way to configure pretty-faces programmatically, without using the pretty-config.xml file?
2. If pretty-config.xml must be used then; is there any way to override/augment its UrlMapppings programmatically?

## Problem Context:

In my situation the mapppings have to come from another xml resource and there are some additional logic towards it. So i devised the following solution
I implemented a ServletContextAttributeListener where I monitor when the prettyConfig object is added to the servlet context by the PrettyFilter

```
@Override
public void attributeAdded(ServletContextAttributeEvent event) {
    Object value = event.getValue();
    if(value != null && value instanceof PrettyConfig){
        PrettyConfig prettyConfig = (PrettyConfig)value ;
        try {
            PrettyFacesConfigProvider provider = new PrettyFacesConfigProvider() ;
            PrettyConfig config = provider.loadConfiguration(event.getServletContext());
            prettyConfig.setMappings(config.getMappings());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CRSWebListener.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

`PrettyFacesConfigProvider` class is the implementation that builds my custom mapping configuration. I inspected the updated config and seems all mappings are added properly. But mappings are not having any effect if I take this route. Ofcourse if I put the mapping in the pretty-config.xml it works perfectly.

I am using pretty-faces 3.3.3, jsf 2.2, prime-faces 4.0, tomcat 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an SPI called [ConfigurationProvider](https://github.com/ocpsoft/prettyfaces/blob/3.3.3/core/src/main/java/com/ocpsoft/pretty/faces/spi/ConfigurationProvider.java) that allows you to implement a custom solution for providing the PrettyFaces configuration. PrettyFaces uses this SPI internally to provided different mechanisms for configuration like [XML](https://github.com/ocpsoft/prettyfaces/blob/3.3.3/core/src/main/java/com/ocpsoft/pretty/faces/config/spi/DefaultXMLConfigurationProvider.java) or [annotations](https://github.com/ocpsoft/prettyfaces/blob/3.3.3/core/src/main/java/com/ocpsoft/pretty/faces/config/spi/AnnotationConfigurationProvider.java). But you can also use the SPI yourself to implement custom ways of building the configuration.

Just create an implementation of `ConfigurationProvider` and then add a file called `META-INF/services/com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.spi.ConfigurationProvider` to your classpath and add the full class name of your implementation class there (see [this example](https://github.com/ocpsoft/prettyfaces/blob/3.3.3/core/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.spi.ConfigurationProvider) for such a file and the javadocs of [ServiceLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) for a descriptions of this plugin mechanism).

Comment: I actually had tried the SPI technique first; but could not make it to work. the class **PrettyFacesConfigProvider** in my code above is actually the very same SPI compliant implementation. After your comment I tried again and it worked. The reason it was not working was that I had put the spi config file in the wrong place. I created a **META-INF/services** in the resource directory, put the file in there and bingo!